# Recompile tex file without modification

Tags: latex, auctex

I `\input{b.tex}` in `a.tex`.

I made changes to `b.tex`, and tried to recompile `a.tex` by `C-c C-c` in AUCTeX, but it didn't work since `a.tex` hadn't been changed.

How can I recompile then?

Comment: Does the manual link to the tex-compile command in the menu-bar work when `a.tex` has not been modified?

Comment: can i select menu in CLI?

Comment: @Tim: do you mean can you select the menu when using Emacs through a terminal emulator?  You should be able to -- alternately, you can hit `f10` (or `M-x menu-bar-open`) to open up the [menu bar](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bar.html).

Answer (score 7):

`C-c C-c` calls `TeX-command-master`, which prompts you for a command (with what it expects you to choose as the default option).  Even if it does not detect that the document has changed, you can always force it to compile by entering `LaTeX` after you `C-c C-c` and it prompts you.